# Would I be able to run a cmd python command with a name that is generated by a list?

Tags: python

Lets say I have a list:

```
my_list = ['first', 'second', 'third']
```

Now what I want to do is run a cmd command that defines a name to this list, but at the same time numbers it. I know this sounds confusing so here is what it would look like:

```
for i in range (0, 4):
      localdevice = cmd("some command create name ARRAY_456_" + i + "")
```

Now I don't need the command itself, that I already have, what I need to know is whether my for loop will work and create `ARRAY_456_1` then `ARRAY_456_2` and then `ARRAY_456_3`?

Or is there some other way that I can add numbers to the end of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work but would write it that way

```
for i in range (0, 4):
      localdevice = cmd("some command create name ARRAY_456_%d" % i)
```

Using string concatenation isn't that clean. Using format to replace parameters in a string is much more flexible

Here's a more complete example:

```
cmd = 'some command create name'
for i in range(4):
    name = 'ARRAY_456_%d' % i # will create ARRAY_456_0, ...
    localdevice = cmd('%(cmd)s %(name)s' % dict(cmd=cmd, name=name)) # will merge the command with the name using keywords
```

If it's not what you're looking for then. I'm not sure to understand the question.

Comment: This would work exactly as I want it thank you :) Just one question is there a way for me to start from 1 could I do:

for i in range(3):

name = 'ARRAY_456_%d' % (i + 1)

Comment: sure but instead you could just use range from one or xrange from one.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
cmd_list = ["first", "second", "third"]
for rank, ze_cmd in enumerate(cmd_list, start=1):
      localdevice = cmd("%s ARRAY_456_%d"%(ze_cmd, rank))
```

This will generate the following cmds :

```
first ARRAY_456_1
second ARRAY_456_2
third ARRAY_456_3
```

Comment: What I was going to write, and is the best approximation of what the OP wants. The question is very poorly worded.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = ["first", "second", "third"]
```

Now you can append more items:

```
my_list.append("fourth")
```

This will append the string `"fourth"` to the end. I think this is what you want, but I'm not sure.

You can of course format the string before appending:

```
for i in xrange(4):
    my_list.append("array_456_%u" % i)
```